# Is there a way to get crisp (instead of fuzzy) blown-up RGraph bar charts?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, rgraph

I am working with a copy of http://www.rgraph.net/demos/bar04.html in which the canvas has no height and width specified in its attributes, but set in CSS to have height and width of 100%.

At present the rendered image looks like it was graphed crisply at a low resolution and then blown up; the screen has the same sort of fuzziness you'll get from zooming too far in on an image in a browser.

Is there any way to adapt and configure RGraph so the image is crisp when the graph fills a screen?

Answer (score 1):

Changing the size of the `canvas` with CSS will just scale it rather than change the innate resolution.  To change the resolution set the `width` and `height` properties of the `canvas`.  You can either do this [in the markup](http://jsfiddle.net/robertc/MGrJy/), or you can set it in script:

```
var cvs = document.getElementById('cvs');
cvs.width = 1200;
cvs.height = 500;
```

Answer (score 0):

As well as hard-coding the values you could determine the window size when the page has loaded (eg with jQuery) and then set the width/height attributes to that.